# Gamerule specific to one person?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I own a minecraft server, and I like playing on survival. Everyone knows I have been playing a while so they always try to kill me. Obviously I could ban these people, but I want to know if there is a way to change the gamerule keepInventory for only myself. It's a bukkit server, and I can implement plugins.

Comment: So I am guessing you can't use god mode since that would be "cheating" for you?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a bukkit server, you could get multiverse inventories and only enable it for you. Other than that there isn't really a "single player" gamerule.